# SurfaceView is triggering NDK crash signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, android-ndk, surfaceview, segmentation-fault

I have no idea about how the issue is reproduced since it is from the native library and it is for only live users. But I am suspecting it is from SurfaceView as it's back stack suggests.

**Device Details:**

**Oppo realme 3Pro (RMX1851), Android 9**

> ERROR

**signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::getLayerState(android::sp const&)**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.test.surfaceview <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000000979c4  /system/lib64/libgui.so (android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::getLayerState(android::sp<android::SurfaceControl> const&)+416)
  #01  pc 0000000000098030  /system/lib64/libgui.so (android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::deferTransactionUntil(android::sp<android::SurfaceControl> const&, android::sp<android::Surface> const&, unsigned long)+48)
  #02  pc 000000000010b1e8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::nativeDeferTransactionUntilSurface(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, long, long)+100)
  #03  pc 0000000000416300  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.SurfaceControl.nativeDeferTransactionUntilSurface+176)
  #04  pc 0000000000ba05c8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction.deferTransactionUntilSurface+136)
  #05  pc 0000000000d42a54  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.SurfaceView.applySurfaceTransforms+132)
  #06  pc 0000000000d46ba0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurfacePosition_renderWorker+752)
  #07  pc 000000000055ab88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #08  pc 00000000000d02c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #09  pc 000000000045f1f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #10  pc 000000000046058c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+440)
  #11  pc 0000000000340fec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656)
  #12  pc 00000000000c78e4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+116)
  #13  pc 0000000000105abc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZZN7androidL46android_view_RenderNode_requestPositionUpdatesEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectlS3_EN26SurfaceViewPositionUpdater21doUpdatePositionAsyncEliiii+204)
  #14  pc 00000000002cef8c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
```

I tried to reproduce in a lot of scenarios but I had no luck.

Let me know if any other info is required.

It would be great if there is an explanation of how this issue can be fixed or fixed.

Comment: OPPO seems to have problems with their 64-bit toolchain, see similar report on [GitHub](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/1058)

Comment: Hi @AlexCohn, Oppo realme 3Pro (RMX1851), Android 9 was the one device which is from many other brands, Mi A1 (tissot_sprout), Android 9 is the most effective device. could it be specific to Android 9, since it is only happening on Android 9?

Comment: ever figure this out? I'm seeing same issue on Android 9 device

Comment: Any updates on this?